# Pyopencl Enqueue Copy is too slow for large buffers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pyopencl

Let us assume that I am executing this simple kernel:

```
__kernel void sine(__global float *res){
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    res[i] = sin((float)i);
}
```

So I am basically computing sine of `n` number of samples. I have a numpy empty array of float32 with shape `n` and a `WRITE_ONLY` buffer of the same size as the numpy array.

Calling that kernel with `n` global size with the input buffer takes about 0.2ms for `n=10000000`, now, using `Equeue Copy` to copy the data from the buffer to the empty array takes about 100ms.

My question is, is it normal to have this time? Is there is anyway to improve it?

Comment: I haven't used Pyopencl yet, but have my experiences with opencl.
It's hard to answer this directly as this depends on the hardware you're using.
If I'm not mistaken you're trying to copy an array with 10000000 float32 from the device the kernel is running on to the host device.
This is roughly a copy of 38 MB (assuming float32  is 4 bytes).
So depending on how quick you can transfer this amount of data, you might have a certain latency.

Further it would be good to show how you're measuring the time, maybe this can give more insights.

Comment: @MartinImre I measured the times by measuring the execution of every step in host code, So kernel execution was measured by measuring the call function, copying was measured by measuring the ClEqueueCopy function. I think there is profiling feature, but I don't know how to use it yet. As for the hardware, I have an AMD HD5450 which is pretty old. I am asking this question just to see if this time make sense or is it something I did wrong that need to be improved. Sorry, don't have much experience.

Comment: How are you measuring those times?
Can you post a complete code example?

Comment: @MartinImre The host code is implemented in a node based system, so I don't need to write any host code. But I can tell you how the node based system do it. It is simply by using getCurrentTime() before and after the operator then subtracting them.

Comment: Here is what I mean by a node based system. All host code is done using nodes and I simply measure the execution time of each node.
http://i.imgur.com/LkRuluT.png

Comment: To measure time in OpenCL you need to use OpenCL-events to guarantee the single steps are completed.
If you're doing that and you still see long times for the read, then, as far as I know, it really takes that long.